# How to show a overlay when Panel is clicked in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have an ActionSheet and a Panel in Sencha Touch 2. I want to show the ActionSheet overlay when the icon-map is clicked in the panel, how can I do that?

Panel.js

```
Ext.define('app.view.principalTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config: {
        ui: 'light',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'mappanel',
                title: 'Map',
                iconCls: 'locate'
            }
        ],
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'bottom',
            ui: 'light'
        }
    }

});
```

asking.js

```
Ext.define('app.view.takePhoto', {
    extend: 'Ext.ActionSheet',

    config: {
        items: [
        {
            text: 'Delete draft',
            ui  : 'decline'
        },
        {
            text: 'Save draft'
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            ui  : 'confirm'
        }
        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a listener to your tab inside the `tab` object of your item.

```
{
    xtype: 'mappanel',
    title: 'Map',
    iconCls: 'locate'
    tab: {
        listeners: {
            tap: function() {
                var sheet = Ext.create('app.view.takePhoto');
                sheet.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside that listener, we create a new instance of your `app.view.takePhoto` class and show it.

Comment: Thanks! that help. but I'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPageBox' of null". Any idea?

Comment: Looks like it is unrelated to the code you have posted, as nothing here refers to that method. You'll need to open another question + post code snippets.

Comment: Are we sure this isn't a ST2 bug?  I get the same error when sheet.show() is called.  Here's SenchaFiddle version: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#iAsdX#UbNAE

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after changing show() to showBy().
Specifying the html id instead of the component did the trick

```
.showBy(Ext.get('ext-tab-5'));
```

instead of

```
.showBy('settingsTab')
```

seems like the method can only be called on DOM elements.

Hope this helps somehow.